# Web API to retrieve data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am creating a web API to retrieve data from a mock database using express

I want to retrieve a JSON list of all portfolios and positions from the database module. Is it possible the data returned to structured so each portfolio has a property with the collection of positions related to each?

```
 const portfolios = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Investor 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Investor 2"
  },

];

const positions = [
  {
    id: 1,
    portfolioId: 1,
    currency: "GBP",
    value: -2.02,
    date: "2018-06-07"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    portfolioId: 1,
    currency: "EUR",
    value: 1906302.15,
    date: "2018-06-07"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    portfolioId: 2,
    currency: "GBP",
    value: 1379804.1,
    date: "2018-06-07"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    portfolioId: 2,
    currency: "CAD",
    value: 2401938.18,
    date: "2018-06-07"
  }
];

export default { portfolios, positions };
```

This is what I have in my router

```
export default (app) => {
  app.get('/portfolio', (req, res) => {
    res.json({ portfolios });
  });
};
```

Comment: As in `portfolios.map (pf => ({...pf, positions: positions.filter (({portfolioId}) => pf.id == portfolioId)}))` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `map` and `filter`.

```
portfolios.map (pf => ({...pf, positions: positions.filter (({portfolioId}) => pf.id == portfolioId)}))
```

Or generalize that idea and use a helper to join your arrays.

```js
function join (left, right, {joinKey,foreignKey, idKey='id'}) {
 return left.map (lI => ({...lI,[joinKey]: right.filter (rI => lI[idKey] == rI[foreignKey])}))
}
let joined = join (portfolios, positions, {joinKey: 'positions', foreignKey: 'portfolioId'})
console.log (joined)
```

```html
<script>

const portfolios = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Investor 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Investor 2"
  },

];

const positions = [
  {
    id: 1,
    portfolioId: 1,
    currency: "GBP",
    value: -2.02,
    date: "2018-06-07"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    portfolioId: 1,
    currency: "EUR",
    value: 1906302.15,
    date: "2018-06-07"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    portfolioId: 2,
    currency: "GBP",
    value: 1379804.1,
    date: "2018-06-07"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    portfolioId: 2,
    currency: "CAD",
    value: 2401938.18,
    date: "2018-06-07"
  }
];

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should look at [lodash](https://lodash.com). It got a lot of usefull function like `filter` to iterate on data.

This should work:

```
export default (app) => {
    app.get('/portfolio', (req, res) => {
        res.json(_.map(portfolios, portfolio => {
            return {
                id: portfolio.id,
                name: portfolio.name,
                positions: _.filter(positions, position => position.portfolioId == portfolio.id)
            }
        }));
    });
};
```

Notice that i don't do `portfolio.positions = _.filter(...)` otherwise the reference inside `portfolios` would be modified. You can explore `_.clone()` if your portfolios become more complex.